# Does librpm provide for querying the RPM database with the syntax found in the SPEC file?

Tags: rpm

Let's [say the SPEC file contains,](http://ftp.rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/dependencies.html)

```
Requires: python >= 1.3, perl
```

Without forging a whole RPM, is there anyway to query the database for whether or not a a query like the following is satisfied by the system installs (without having to install further packages),

```
python >= 1.3, perl
```

Can I query the database for `python >= 1.3, perl` using base tools, or the underlying librpm?

I see I can query to see whether or not I have Python with,

```
$ rpm -q "python"
python-2.7.5-76.el7.x86_64
```

And likewise with perl, but is there anyway to to provide a query string and get back whether or not the dependencies are satisfied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the shelf, no. However if you split on comma you can produce the version list of the software

```
rpm --qf '%{NAME}:%{VERSION}\n' -q -- perl
rpm --qf '%{NAME}:%{VERSION}\n' -q -- python
```

As I work more on this problem I plan on updating this.